# How padding=zeros works in pytorch in functional.conv1d

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, padding, conv1d

This following code below giving a output of shape `(1,1,3)` for the shape of `xodd` is `(1,1,2)`. The given kernel shape is`(112, 1, 1)`.

```
from torch.nn import functional as F
output = F.conv1d(xodd, kernel, padding=zeros)
```

How the `padding=zeros` works?
And also, How can I write an equivalent code in tensorflow so that the output is as same as the above `output`?

Comment: You didn't provide how the variable `zeros` was defined. I'm guessing `zeros` is equal to either `(0,1)` or `(1,0)` to get the shape you describe. If these cases `conv1d` implicitly appends or prepends a zero along the last dimension before applying convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is `padding=zeros`?**
If we set `paddin=zeros`, we don't need to add numbers at the right and the left of the tensor.

**Padding=0**:

```
from torch.nn import functional as F
import torch
inputs = torch.randn(33, 16, 6) # (minibatch,in_channels,features)
filters = torch.randn(20, 16, 5) # (out_channels, in_channels, kernel_size)
out_tns = F.conv1d(inputs, filters, stride=1, padding=0)
print(out_tns.shape)
# torch.Size([33, 20, 2]) # (minibatch,out_channels,(features-kernel_size+1))
```

[image]

**Padding=2:**(We want to add two numbers at the right and the left of the tensor)

```
inputs = torch.randn(33, 16, 6) # (minibatch,in_channels,features)
filters = torch.randn(20, 16, 5) # (out_channels, in_channels, kernel_size)
out_tns = F.conv1d(inputs, filters, stride=1, padding=2)
print(out_tns.shape)
# torch.Size([33, 20, 6]) # (minibatch,out_channels,(features-kernel_size+1+2+2))
```

[image]

**How can I write an equivalent code in tensorflow:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_shape = (33, 6, 16)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
out_tf = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 20, 
                                kernel_size = 5,
                                strides = 1, 
                                input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(out_tf.shape)
# TensorShape([33, 2, 20])

# If you want that tensor have shape exactly like pytorch you can transpose
tf.transpose(out_tf, [0, 2, 1]).shape
# TensorShape([33, 20, 2])
```